# Flutter - Check if array element is null

Tags: dart, flutter

I´m trying to check if object has a null element. For do this I iterate a list and check if has data, finally I need to check if one element of this list is null. If is null doesn´t add to the data list, if has data, add to data list.

```
List data = List();

final responseJson = json.decode(response.body) as List;
     if (responseJson!=null){
          for (Map data in responseJson) {
               if(data[‘name']=!null){ <- I need to ignore elements that doesn't have name, but all element (including elements without name) pass for this if.
                    list.add(response[‘name’]):
               }
          }
     }
```

What is the right way to ignore element that does not contains name and add in the list the elements with name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use

```
for (Map data in responseJson.where((d) => d.containsKey('name'))) {
```

it might need

```
for (Map data in responseJson.where((d) => (d as Map).containsKey('name'))) {
```

Comment: And how can i pass multiple element? for (Map data in responseJson.where((d) => d.containsKey('name') && d.containsKey('id'))) { ?